# Linq query not functioning as expected

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to write a ling query which essentially looks at a serial number inside the header of a msg object and checks if any exist which have same values as values in list1. I'm new to Linq and gave it a try but no luck. Any help will be appreciated!

```
for (int i =0; i < list1.Count; i++)
{
    List<int> list1;
    list1.Add("3333");
    string c = msg = (list1[i] => msg.Header.SerialNumber = list1[i].ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(c);
}
```

Comment: I don't see any LINQ.  What does 'no luck' mean?  What is `list1`?  What is `msg`?  Please give a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows your problem.

Comment: Looks like you just need to read some intro tutorials on LINQ and just C# in general.

Comment: first learn c# before trying lambda expressions

Comment: This code looks like a mess. Take the advice and do some c# basics first before tackling anything more complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query can be made much simpler, assuming list1 is the array with potential header numbers and both the serial number and the array contents have compatible data types:

```
list1.Any(v => v.Equals(msg.Header.SerialNumber))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int count = list1.Count(i=>i.value == msg.Header.SerialNumber);
if(count == 0){ Console.WriteLine(msg);}
```